# Open store with Soomla Framework (Cocos 2dx)

Tags: cocos2d-x, soomla

I don't really understand what is the utility of this operation:

```
soomla::CCStoreController::sharedStoreController()->storeOpening();
```

In the documentation it is said this should be called when you want to show the storefront, but I'm coding my own storefront.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is required when you want to access inapp purchage otherwise it is not required

Comment: Yes I knew it was required. Just was wondering why.

Comment: Soom.la is big mess and flawed. I would suggest you to write you own JNI bridge functions to use Billing in  android.

Comment: The truth is soomla saved me a lot of time of development... I highly recommend the use of this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have removed those functions. You don't need to call `storeOpening()` and `storeClosing()` anymore.

If you're on Android AND you have your own storefront, you should call `startIabServiceInBg()` and `stopIabServiceInBg()` when you open and close your storefront. You don't have to do that though.

Comment: I just was seeing the 4.1.2 tag from yesterday right now and reading the comments about it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`storeOpening()` and `storeClosing()` methods are just for create and delete Store instance for platform API's. If you are creating Store Layer then just call them in `onEnter()` and `onExit()` methods respectively.